# How do I change rangeSlider default starting minimum and maximum values so I can store and retrieve from a DB Table

Tags: javascript, php, rangeslider

By default, the rangeSlider plug in calculates default values of 33 min and 66 max.  The code below is completely functional, around line 125 I have further comments on where I think my solution resides.  Remove and add // to see what I am talking about.  I hope this makes sence and thanks in advance for any help

```
    <?php
        $qty_min  = isset($_REQUEST['qty_min']) ? $_REQUEST['qty_min'] : "33";
        $qty_max = isset($_REQUEST['qty_max']) ? $_REQUEST['qty_max'] : "66";
        $first_load = "false";
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Dashboard - SB Admin</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css" />

    <style>
        /*   RANGE SLIDER BAR REGULAR CSS  */

        .primaryText{
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 50px;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        .secondaryText{
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 25px;
        }
        .createdBy {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 17px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .createdBy a{
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
        .message {
            background: white;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
            margin: 25px 0;
            font-size: 13px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .projHeader{
            text-align: center;
        }

        .footer{position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: auto; top: auto; left: 0; border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width: 100%; transform: translate(0); border: none; padding: 0; text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #bfc7e4;}
        .footer div{display: inline-block;}
        .footer a.social{display: inline-block; font-size: 17px; padding: 7px 0; color: #000; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px 20px;}

        body{background: #333; font-family: poppins;}
        .projHeader, .createdBy a, .message{color: #fff;}
        .message{background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}

        .demoContainer{position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 40%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); width: 400px;} 
        .sliderContainer{position: relative; border-radius: 20px; 
            background: #6a6a6a; width: 400px; height: 10px; margin-top: 40px;}
        .sliderContainer:after{content:""; clear: both; display: block; }
        .slider{height: 10px; float: left;}
        .slider_a{background: transparent;}
        .slider_b{background: #fd1874; border-radius: 20px;}
        .slider_c{background: transparent;}

        .slider_adj{position: absolute; padding: 3px 10px; background: #fff; top: 12px; cursor: move; user-select: none; z-index: 1; font-size: 13px; color: #333; border-radius: 20px; width: 20px; text-align: center;}
        .slider_adj_1{top: -28px;}
        .slider_adj_2{z-index: 3}
    </style>

    <div class="projHeader">
        <div style="background:rgb(124, 124, 124);padding-bottom:40px;">
            <div style="color:white;font-size:16px;font-weight: 100">  Slide the numbered ovals to select your desired range.</div>
            <div align="center">
                <div class="sliderContainer" id="sliderContainer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="qty_min" id="qty_min" value="<?php echo $qty_min ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $qty_min ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="qty_max" id="qty_max" value="<?php echo $qty_max ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $qty_max ?>" />
                    <div class="slider slider_a" id="slider_a"></div>
                    <div class="slider slider_b" id="slider_b"></div>
                    <div class="slider slider_c" id="slider_c"></div>

                    <div style="width:70px" class="slider_adj slider_adj_1"  id="slider_adj_1"></div>     
                    <div style="width:70px" class="slider_adj slider_adj_2"  id="slider_adj_2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="color:white"> var-a_wt = <span id="var-a_wt"></span></div>
        <div style="color:white"> var-b_wt = <span id="var-b_wt"></span></div>
        <div style="color:white"> var-c_wt = <span id="var-c_wt"></span></div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


    <script>
        var sliderContainer, sliderContainerWt;
        var sliderHandleWt;
        $(document).ready(function(){
        sliderContainer = $("#sliderContainer");
        sliderContainerWt = sliderContainer.outerWidth();
        sliderHandleWt = $("#slider_adj_1").outerWidth();

        setLeftPosition();
        setDraggable();
        bindMouseUp();
        updateGraph();
        });

        function setLeftPosition(){
        var wt = sliderContainerWt/3;
        $(".slider").css({"width": wt+"px" })
```

The two lines below work great, but I need to change default values on the fly, then store them in a DB table to restore custom values on page reload. The two lines below calculate 33 and 66 only

```
        //var sliderHandlePos_1 = wt-sliderHandleWt/2;
        //var sliderHandlePos_2 = wt*2-sliderHandleWt/2;
```

The two lines below kind of work, but throws off the format of my slider bar and min and max values are still not right

```
        var sliderHandlePos_1 = '<?php echo $qty_min ?>';
        var sliderHandlePos_2 = '<?php echo $qty_max ?>';


        $("#slider_adj_1").css({"left": sliderHandlePos_1+"px"});
        $("#slider_adj_2").css({"left": sliderHandlePos_2+"px"});
        }
    </script>


    <script>
        function updateGraph(){
```

I think my solution is in the next 3 lines of code, but my limited skills in javascript inhibit me from wrapping my head around it.

```
            var a_wt = parseInt(($("#slider_a").width()/sliderContainerWt*100).toFixed(0));
            var b_wt = parseInt(($("#slider_b").width()/sliderContainerWt*100).toFixed(0));
            var c_wt = parseInt(($("#slider_c").width()/sliderContainerWt*100).toFixed(0));
```

I have tried the following, but no luck.  I need the initial values to load from the table via PHP just once, then java script takes back over and keeps track of slider values, as YES I understand PHP is server side script, so I understand why this does not work.  Just and example>  I need a JavaScript equivalent.

```
      var a_wt = <?php echo $qty_min ?>;
      var b_wt = <?php echo ($qty_max-$qty_min) ?>;
      var c_wt = <?php echo (100-$qty_max) ?>;
```

I don't think my solution is beyond this point.  But of course I could be wrong.

```
            $("#slider_adj_1").html(a_wt+"%");
            $("#slider_adj_2").html((b_wt+a_wt)+"%");
            
            document.getElementById('qty_min').value = a_wt;
            document.getElementById('qty_max').value = b_wt+a_wt;

            document.getElementById('var-a_wt').innerHTML = a_wt;
            document.getElementById('var-b_wt').innerHTML = b_wt;
            document.getElementById('var-c_wt').innerHTML = c_wt;

            return { a: a_wt, 
                    b: b_wt,
                    c: c_wt 
                    }
        }
    </script>


    <script>
        function bindMouseUp(){
            $("#slider_adj_1, #slider_adj_2").on("mouseout", function(){
                $("#slider_adj_1, #slider_adj_2").draggable( "destroy" );
            });
            $("#slider_adj_1, #slider_adj_2").on("mouseover", function(){
                setDraggable();
            });
        }

        function setDraggable(){
            var maxLeft = $("#slider_a").offset().left-(sliderHandleWt/2);
            var maxRight = $("#slider_b").offset().left+$("#slider_b").outerWidth()-(sliderHandleWt/2);
            var startX, start_a_Wt, start_b_Wt, start_c_Wt;
            $("#slider_adj_1").draggable({
                axis: 'x',
                containment: [ maxLeft, 0, maxRight, 0 ],
                refreshPositions: true,
                start: function(event, ui){
                startX = $(this).position().left;
                start_a_Wt = $("#slider_a").width();
                start_b_Wt = $("#slider_b").width();
                },
                drag: function(event, ui){
                var endX = $(this).position().left;
                var finalX = endX - startX;
                var slider_a = start_a_Wt + finalX;
                var slider_b = start_b_Wt - finalX;
                $("#slider_a").css("width", slider_a+"px");
                $("#slider_b").css("width", slider_b+"px");
                updateGraph();
                },
                stop: function(event, ui){
                maxLeft = $("#slider_a").position().left;
                maxRight = $("#slider_c").position().left;
            }
        });

        var maxLeft_2 = $("#slider_a").offset().left+$("#slider_a").outerWidth()-(sliderHandleWt/2);
        var maxRight_2 = $("#slider_a").offset().left+sliderContainerWt-(sliderHandleWt/2);


        $("#slider_adj_2").draggable({
            axis: 'x',
            containment: [ maxLeft_2, 0, maxRight_2, 0 ],
            start: function(event, ui){
                startX = $(this).position().left;
                start_b_Wt = $("#slider_b").width();
                start_c_Wt = $("#slider_c").width();
            },
            drag: function(event, ui){
                var endX = $(this).position().left;
                var finalX = endX - startX;
                var slider_b = start_b_Wt + finalX;
                var slider_c = start_c_Wt - finalX;
                $("#slider_b").css("width", slider_b+"px");
                $("#slider_c").css("width", slider_c+"px");
                updateGraph();
            },
            stop: function(event, ui){
                maxLeft_2 = $("#slider_b").offset().left;
                maxRight_2 = $("#slider_c").offset().left + $("#slider_c").width();
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was completely going down the wrong path.  After reading further in the PROPER documentation, I came up with the following completely functioning code, just in case this helps someone else.  I also show how to explode the my_range variable so now you can store these variable in a database table.  Great documentation at http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/start.html

```
    <?php
    $my_range  = isset($_REQUEST['my_range']) ? $_REQUEST['my_range'] : "";
    $split_range = (explode(";",$my_range));

    $qty_min = $split_range[0];
    $qty_max = $split_range[1];
    ?>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.3.1/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>

    <form action="slider_test2.php" method="post">
        <input style="color:blue" type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" />
        <br>
        <?php echo "my_range = " . $my_range; ?>
        <?php echo "<br>qty_min = " . $qty_min; ?>
        <?php echo "<br>qty_max = " . $qty_max; ?>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" >submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
        type: "double",
        grid: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        from: <?php echo $qty_min ?>,
        to: <?php echo $qty_max ?>,
        postfix: "%",
        skin: "big"
        
    });
    </script>
```